# How does the RDF module impact user mapping when using the Acquia Migrate Accelerate (AMA) tool?

Tags: 9, rdf

Before Acquia's AMA tool was open source, I used it on their platform to upgrade from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9. I am in the process of upgrading to Drupal 10 and want to uninstall the RDF module (don't know why it's there as it was never used on my Drupal 7 site), but get a warning that the RDF mapping user.user configuration will be deleted. Because I do not know how the AMA tool was designed, I'm not sure what to expect if I uninstall this module. Should I expect an issue with the user accounts (migration mapping)?